TabBar in the middle of the screen should show 3 different pages
I added in the middle of my screen a tab view with : Services, Products , Reviews. I don't know what info I should add to my ServicesScreen , ProductsScreen and ReviewScreen to receive this autcome  The page that has this info is scrollable
By now this is what I added to my code by if I uncomment the ServicesScreen, ProductScreen and ReviewScreen a get a red line under tabController. What I should add in their individual pages, here it's the code for ServicesScreen
  TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
              labelColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 3, 59, 161),
              tabs: const [
                Tab(
                  text: 'Services',
                ),
                Tab(text: 'Products'),
                Tab(
                  text: 'Reviews',
                ),
              ],
              controller: tabController,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
            ),
            //        Expanded(
            // child: TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: [
            //   Servicesscreen(tabController: tabController),
            //  Productsscreen(tabController: tabController),
            //  Reviewscreen(tabController: tabController),
            // ]),

            //   ),
          ]),

The code for ServicesScreen
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Servicesscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ServicescreenState createState() => _ServicescreenState();
}

class _ServicescreenState extends State<Servicesscreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
    enter code here


whats the problem with your current code?
You should simply define 3 different screens, and then use them in the TabBarView.
If you are receive errors, please [edit] your question to include the traceback.

I think the TabBarView is inside a scrollable widget and as you are using Expanded to make TabBarView to expand, you might be getting infinite height constraint error, right?

Ok, so i saw video of your prblm in another question. The first issue was the no. of screens in TabBarView does not matches the no. of widget defined in the controller when you initialized it. You are only giving 3 screen but when defining controller you used 4 not 3. Second is related to use of expanded incorrectly.

I've changed with 3, still same issue with the redline under tabController

@sanda17 Is your Servicesscreen content is scrollable or whole content with tabbar is scrollable?

Entire it's scrollable
